# Is GGeffects what I want to use to plot my linear mixed effect model results

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, ggplot2

So I am interested in how participants' own preference ratings for a series of items predicts their ratings for a peer's preferences for the same items. My model looks something like below where they make ratings under two conditions (learn_prof).

```
td_pref_all_strat <- lmer(rating ~ 
                         learn_prof +
                         own_pref +
                         learn_prof * own_pref +
                        (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
```

The data set appears like the sample I have below:

```
structure(list(subject = c("6090919e35432ed7cf716ca4", "5ea35bfe13923f2ca4ce450b", 
"5f4b109ca1429a16b160807c", "5e7f514bb18cb4000a68310d", "5dd9df0e946f7c97406a55ea", 
"5ede2d7dc4e2d10431fbac60", "60fceb63bd7ca52152c7362c", "5d0fbedf101793000168ef7a", 
"5f9822ed09bb3d07b22d6c8d", "5eb5301f97cece03ad0e0263", "5ee9f0fa87dec101cd15d4c4", 
"5e52d61b9bfb34032e5b6304", "6000ca0be380e61f33f7a0fa", "5b108e8e1e55760001b9c78e", 
"5dd9df0e946f7c97406a55ea", "5f6ea775bc475b407020431f", "5f3189b34698b4059916f5d0", 
"5f2a5f187bf471245f7dc096", "60a647cf71f87619eeed97ea", "629b145d8c743623fb5f1cbb", 
"60abd5ba97921106bca53aff", "5f1338a87447d0308e865fd0", "5f148987fe732f4f78528c34", 
"60c381c26357c51532f1b378", "610881055b4f5daa95c3118c", "5f1b2c6bb5afc42e312b436a", 
"6096327643602d17a3930038", "5c353d803c56f500011a04dc", "5f50aeae3f09db22047804d9", 
"5c3314c6f28f2600010e4e83", "5c3314c6f28f2600010e4e83", "5d5a87cdb8d49300195674d6", 
"629b145d8c743623fb5f1cbb", "5f4e3cb2ab878aa1985bf0c1", "5f0ce143b27853527391bdbb", 
"60fcd0fcf53c82218fc96669", "5eaa192b4e2ab9197cec6eeb", "5d96eeed1998fb00177f6b71", 
"5f1b2c6bb5afc42e312b436a", "60a647cf71f87619eeed97ea", "5f2a5f187bf471245f7dc096", 
"5caf451e7692490017d22482", "5eb5301f97cece03ad0e0263", "5eeaa065c7acf61c4322f6d9", 
"5fcbbb5dd4b95a92976be0ef", "5f2226ed22f0956bf55ddb71", "607f1f1b945e95af870d0dec", 
"5f9e40344dbd1f3ea731975d", "5e3b89a10d41ad3a7bc35011", "5f50aeae3f09db22047804d9"
), age = c(22L, 20L, 18L, 23L, 20L, 24L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 
21L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 21L, 24L, 20L, 23L, 20L, 19L, 
21L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 20L, 24L, 21L, 19L, 
19L, 23L, 19L, 24L, 21L, 23L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
25L), sex = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), race = c("5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", 
"4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "2", "5", "5", "5", "2", "2,5,6", 
"5", "2", "5", "4,5,6", "5", "1,2,5,6", "5", "4", "2", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "4,5", "2", "5", "4", "2", "5", "2", "4", "5", "2,5,6", 
"5", "5", "1", "2", "5", "5", "5", "2", "5"), bapq = c(3.861111111, 
3.47222222, 3.916666667, 3.194444444, 3.333333333, 2.944444444, 
3.58333333, 3.16666667, 2.472222222, 3.722222222, 3.444444444, 
3.111111111, 3.47222222, 3.138888889, 3.333333333, 2.611111111, 
2.888888889, 3.5, 2.972222222, 3.13888889, 3.166666667, 3.52777778, 
2.88888889, 4.58333333, 3.75, 3.361111111, 3.222222222, 3.361111111, 
3.194444444, 3.111111111, 3.111111111, 2.361111111, 3.13888889, 
2.638888889, 4.444444444, 3.472222222, 3.333333333, 3.166666667, 
3.361111111, 2.972222222, 3.5, 3.416666667, 3.722222222, 3.611111111, 
3.611111111, 2.444444444, 2.194444444, 3.277777778, 3.111111111, 
3.194444444), event = c(116L, 63L, 26L, 63L, 17L, 17L, 75L, 47L, 
45L, 85L, 65L, 47L, 24L, 62L, 9L, 56L, 33L, 104L, 40L, 71L, 112L, 
80L, 104L, 2L, 95L, 90L, 8L, 89L, 119L, 47L, 104L, 18L, 40L, 
109L, 16L, 30L, 115L, 5L, 47L, 78L, 31L, 69L, 31L, 102L, 84L, 
116L, 116L, 69L, 65L, 104L), timestamp = c("6/7/21 15:32", "7/1/22 16:46", 
"11/16/20 19:19", "11/24/20 14:56", "11/24/20 14:20", "11/24/20 14:39", 
"7/1/22 16:50", "7/1/22 14:38", "7/1/22 14:10", "11/16/20 20:32", 
"11/16/20 18:58", "6/7/21 15:25", "7/1/22 14:39", "11/17/20 15:45", 
"11/24/20 14:18", "11/24/20 14:50", "11/24/20 14:09", "7/1/22 13:25", 
"6/7/21 14:13", "7/1/22 15:13", "6/7/21 14:10", "7/1/22 15:03", 
"7/1/22 16:52", "7/1/22 16:21", "7/1/22 16:39", "6/7/21 15:30", 
"6/7/21 13:52", "11/16/20 19:21", "6/7/21 14:35", "6/7/21 15:21", 
"6/7/21 15:29", "11/24/20 14:08", "7/1/22 15:04", "6/7/21 15:00", 
"11/16/20 20:10", "7/1/22 14:30", "11/16/20 20:25", "11/24/20 14:09", 
"6/7/21 15:24", "6/7/21 14:21", "7/1/22 13:14", "11/16/20 18:59", 
"11/16/20 20:24", "11/16/20 19:07", "6/7/21 15:31", "6/7/21 15:40", 
"6/7/21 15:45", "11/16/20 20:25", "11/16/20 23:09", "6/7/21 14:33"
), condition = c("odd", "mean", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", 
"odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", 
"mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", "odd", "odd", "mean", 
"odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", "mean", "mean", "odd", "mean", "mean", 
"odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", 
"mean", "mean", "odd", "odd", "mean", "mean", "mean", "mean", 
"mean"), rating = c(3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
5, 4, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 2, 
3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4), rt_ms = c(5964, 
1238, 3008, 1899, 3091, 1771, 2439, 1418, 1840, 1817, 1384, 1722, 
2079, 2517, 1665, 1172, 1780, 845, 4568, 1684, 4626, 2311, 2422, 
3157, 1857, 1284, 2321, 1588, 1584, 2523, 981, 1398, 1610, 2506, 
2882, 775, 1138, 3990, 2922, 3845, 1398, 3442, 1241, 1212, 1213, 
4580, 4049, 1493, 1784, 2495), image = c("oil_4", "notebook_1", 
"bagel_1", "ball_02", "radio_2", "bacon_01", "bagel_2", "cake2", 
"taco_01", "baNaNaN_01", "skateboard_03", "soup_01", "ball_01", 
"burger_02", "camera_2", "chocolate5", "accordion_1", "microscope_1", 
"apple_01", "chocolate5", "pokerchips_01", "veggie_01", "radio_2", 
"cake2", "sandwich_4", "pizza_02", "frisbee_1", "ball_01", "snorkling_02", 
"greens_02", "snorkling_02", "bun_1", "wrap_01", "fitness_02", 
"ice_skates_04", "cake3", "carrots_01", "candy_3", "chicken_2", 
"headphones_3", "sandwich_1", "berries_02", "gratin_01", "boomerang_2", 
"chess_3", "drums_1", "chicken_2", "pizza_04", "bagel_1", "oil_3"
), trial = c(55L, 2L, 25L, 2L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 46L, 44L, 24L, 
4L, 46L, 23L, 1L, 8L, 55L, 32L, 43L, 39L, 10L, 51L, 19L, 43L, 
1L, 34L, 29L, 7L, 28L, 58L, 46L, 43L, 17L, 39L, 48L, 15L, 29L, 
54L, 4L, 46L, 17L, 30L, 8L, 30L, 41L, 23L, 55L, 55L, 8L, 4L, 
43L), onset_s = c(978.532, 707.24, 214.478, 528.321, 136.314, 
137.251, 644.438, 343.909, 333.402, 728.881, 588.304, 357.57, 
181.47, 562.134, 70.827, 395.996, 275.352, 837.35, 370.346, 825.893, 
1021.077, 674.64, 947.949, 12.017, 776.161, 739.405, 67.108, 
754.729, 1166.695, 355.987, 816.242, 133.979, 328.325, 987.42, 
121.798, 212.059, 858.418, 39.342, 390.278, 856.455, 225.959, 
710.598, 233.332, 892.682, 723.168, 1074.347, 1102.735, 759.189, 
608.893, 1043.489), profile_rating = c(5L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L), block = c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), sub_num = c(29L, 116L, 34L, 194L, 178L, 186L, 122L, 90L, 
76L, 118L, 10L, 40L, 93L, 137L, 178L, 192L, 159L, 68L, 16L, 105L, 
9L, 102L, 119L, 107L, 109L, 38L, 8L, 28L, 20L, 30L, 30L, 160L, 
105L, 24L, 100L, 86L, 72L, 166L, 38L, 16L, 68L, 9L, 118L, 12L, 
39L, 42L, 43L, 111L, 132L, 20L), item_num = c(114L, 109L, 11L, 
14L, 104L, 9L, 18L, 42L, 151L, 15L, 110L, 146L, 19L, 28L, 36L, 
49L, 1L, 97L, 3L, 60L, 127L, 155L, 129L, 42L, 137L, 125L, 76L, 
13L, 145L, 79L, 145L, 27L, 157L, 74L, 76L, 43L, 40L, 38L, 56L, 
87L, 136L, 19L, 63L, 24L, 54L, 69L, 56L, 101L, 11L, 113L), cat1 = c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L), cat2 = c(1L, 1L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 
11L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 4L, 11L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 
2L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 1L), profile_rating_new = c(3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L), PE = c(0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2), PE_si = c(0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 
3, -2, 4, -1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 1, 4, 3, 4, 
2, 1, 1, 3, 2, -1, 3, 1, 2, -1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
2, 1, 2, 0, 2), pro_PE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L), mean_p1 = c(4.080851064, 
2.838297872, 4.242553191, 3.829787234, 3.319148936, 4.272340426, 
4.170212766, 4.046808511, 4.578723404, 4.506382979, 3.421276596, 
3.625531915, 3.425531915, 4.659574468, 4.536170213, 4.353191489, 
3.212765957, 3.761702128, 4.468085106, 4.353191489, 3.395744681, 
3.582978723, 3.319148936, 4.046808511, 4.144680851, 4.787234043, 
3.34893617, 3.425531915, 3.519148936, 3.404255319, 3.519148936, 
4.446808511, 4.123404255, 3.953191489, 3.272340426, 4.429787234, 
3.45106383, 4.391489362, 3.787234043, 4.425531915, 4.259574468, 
4.89787234, 3.774468085, 3.2, 3.634042553, 3.825531915, 3.787234043, 
4.89787234, 4.242553191, 3.791489362), X = c(3.848484848, 2.878787879, 
3.848484848, 4.055555556, 2.963636364, 4.416666667, 4.013888889, 
4.012121212, 4.412121212, 4.180555556, 3.555555556, 3.513888889, 
3.387878788, 4.03030303, 4.2, 4.254545455, 2.963636364, 3.739393939, 
4.303030303, 4.254545455, 3.272727273, 3.638888889, 2.963636364, 
4.012121212, 3.539393939, 4.402777778, 3.509090909, 3.387878788, 
3.696969697, 3.527272727, 3.696969697, 4.327272727, 3.618181818, 
3.660606061, 3.613636364, 4.277777778, 3.652777778, 4.496969697, 
3.484848485, 4.054545455, 3.791666667, 4.624242424, 3.424242424, 
3.345454545, 3.909090909, 3.751515152, 3.484848485, 4.424242424, 
3.848484848, 3.715151515), mean_p3 = c(4.238267148, 3.407942238, 
3.859205776, 3.602888087, 3.512635379, 4.729241877, 3.750902527, 
4.346570397, 4.241877256, 4.339350181, 3.407942238, 3.064981949, 
3.870036101, 4.386281588, 4.25631769, 4.541516245, 2.920577617, 
4.036101083, 4.241877256, 4.541516245, 3.032490975, 3.083032491, 
3.512635379, 4.346570397, 3.21299639, 4.776173285, 3.711191336, 
3.870036101, 4.014440433, 2.682310469, 4.014440433, 4.750902527, 
3.155234657, 3.379061372, 3.003610108, 4.707581227, 3.079422383, 
5.014440433, 2.909747292, 4.794223827, 3.613718412, 4.469314079, 
2.78700361, 3.368231047, 3.592057762, 3.729241877, 2.909747292, 
5.187725632, 3.859205776, 4.018050542), own_pref = c(3L, 1L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 4L
), med_p = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 
3, 4, 4.5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4), own_pref_nan = c(3, 
1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 3, 6, 6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 
4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 3, 6, 1, 5, 5, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 5, 4), learn_prof = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), group = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), row.names = c(17970L, 13885L, 8771L, 5054L, 3584L, 6369L, 
20172L, 12271L, 16435L, 5655L, 6830L, 13553L, 16933L, 1228L, 
3516L, 769L, 8161L, 14838L, 18123L, 22489L, 18462L, 14279L, 14384L, 
19471L, 20988L, 14500L, 18061L, 1573L, 15472L, 12784L, 12832L, 
2427L, 22560L, 15060L, 7516L, 20072L, 5440L, 2918L, 14445L, 18191L, 
14867L, 1939L, 5703L, 6864L, 16603L, 14577L, 17685L, 11021L, 
4091L, 15449L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am interested in basically plotting the interaction between learn_prof and own preferences as predictors of participants ratings. I have been using `GGeffects` to accomplish this with code that looks something like this:

```
ggpredict(td_pref_all_strat, terms = c("own_pref","learn_prof"))
```

This computes a prediction of a rating for each own preferences rating for each of the learning profile. I then plot this with the code below:

```
td_pref_all_summ <- as_tibble(td_pref_all)
td_summStats_all <- td_pref_all_summ   %>%
  group_by(image, learn_prof) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    mean_own = mean(own_pref, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean_rate = mean(rating, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(rating, na.rm = TRUE))

p1 <- ggplot(td_pref_own_plot, aes(x, predicted, col = group)) +
      geom_line(size=1.5) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("grey40","darkorchid4")) +
      geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=conf.low,ymax=conf.high, fill=group),alpha=.2,colour=NA) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey40","darkorchid4")) +
      geom_point(data=td_summStats_all, aes(mean_own, mean_rate, col = as.factor(learn_prof)),size=2) +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("grey40","darkorchid4")) +
      theme_bw() +
      xlab('Self-preferences') +
      ylab("Subject Rating") +
      ylim(2,6)
      theme(text=element_text(size=20),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.border = element_blank())
p1
```

The fit when I do this with the whole data set is off though. I'm not sure if I'm using `GGpredict` correctly though or if something is wrong with my actual model. I found some tutorials on GGeffects but they were using linear regression models so I just want to make sure this makes sense for a linear-mixed effects model. Are their alternative ways to plot my linear mixed effects model results if this is incorrect?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the fit is off"?

Comment: It looks as though the regression lines don't really line up with the trend of the scatter for each condition (for lack of a better description). Each dot basically represents an one of the 60 items and it's "average" own_preference rating plotted against the subject's rating.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you're mixing the predictions and mean values of your data. This might explain, why the data points may look a bit "off". You can show data points directly using `ggpredict()` resp. the `plot()` method, and you can show "lack of fit" with [partial residuals](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_partial_residuals.html). Does this help?

```r
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)
m <- lmer(rating ~ learn_prof * own_pref + (1 | subject) + (1 | image), data = d)
#> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

ggpredict(m, terms = c("own_pref", "learn_prof")) |> plot(show_data = TRUE, jitter = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggpredict(m, terms = c("own_pref", "learn_prof")) |>
  plot(show_residuals = TRUE, show_residuals_line = TRUE)
#> Data points may overlap. Use the `jitter` argument to add some amount of
#>   random variation to the location of data points and avoid overplotting.
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula = 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>